# how to filter Json objects with checkbox using Ajax and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am new here and my first question on stack overflow, I am working trying to get the JSON object by filtering with checkbox value by using jQuery and AJAX. For example, if I click on showroom sales it will return me all object value which carries showroom sales.

```
<div id="checkbox_div">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="showroom sales">showroom sales</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Service Center">Service Center</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Quick Service">Quick Service</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Spare Parts">Spare Parts</label>
</div>
<ol id="container"></ol>
```

and here is my jquery and json values. please someone help me to sort out this problem. i will be really hopeful to you. please

```
$('checkbox_div input').click(function(){
    var serv_val = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON( "petromin.json", function(data) { 
        $.each(data, function(key, value) { 
            $("ol").append("<li>" + value.services_list + "</li>");
        });

    });
});

  [
{
  "showroomname": "karama",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "4m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Spare Parts", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Dubai"
},
{
  "showroomname": "financial center",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "44.3 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Service Centre", "Spare Parts" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Dubai"
},
{
  "showroomname": "downtown",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "213.6 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Service Centre", "Spare Parts", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Dubai"
},
{
  "showroomname": "jumierah",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "100 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Service Centre", "Spare Parts", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Dubai"
},
{
  "showroomname": "Al Qouz",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "213.6 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Service Centre", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Dubai"
},
{
  "showroomname": "Al Barsha",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "213.6 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Spare Parts", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Dubai"
},
{
  "showroomname": "Al Masaood Automobiles - Nissan, Infiniti Showroom",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "44.3 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Service Centre", "Spare Parts" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Abu Dhabi"
},
{
  "showroomname": "FLEET SHOWROOM",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "213.6 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Service Centre", "Spare Parts", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Abu Dhabi"
},
{
  "showroomname": "INFINITI",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "100 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Service Centre", "Spare Parts", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Abu Dhabi"
},
{
  "showroomname": "Ford Showroom",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "213.6 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Service Centre", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Abu Dhabi"
},
{
  "showroomname": "Al Habtoor Motors Royal Car",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "213.6 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Spare Parts", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Abu Dhabi"
}

  ]
```

Comment: `$('checkbox_div input')` You're missing the `#` on your id.  And your question doesn't state what problem you are having.  If the only issue is that incorrect selector, I'll vote to close as a typo.

Comment: its not about the `#`  actually i am getting all value from all objects

Comment: The missing `#` is definitely an issue.  So is your question how to filter?  Reference: [MDN Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: yes dear by mistakenly i forgot to put `#` there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use [array filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const arr = 
  [
{
  "showroomname": "karama",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "4m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Spare Parts", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Dubai"
},
{
  "showroomname": "financial center",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "44.3 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Service Centre", "Spare Parts" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Dubai"
},
{
  "showroomname": "downtown",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "213.6 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Service Centre", "Spare Parts", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Dubai"
},
{
  "showroomname": "jumierah",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "100 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Service Centre", "Spare Parts", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Dubai"
},
{
  "showroomname": "Al Qouz",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "213.6 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Service Centre", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Dubai"
},
{
  "showroomname": "Al Barsha",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "213.6 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Spare Parts", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Dubai"
},
{
  "showroomname": "Al Masaood Automobiles - Nissan, Infiniti Showroom",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "44.3 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Service Centre", "Spare Parts" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Abu Dhabi"
},
{
  "showroomname": "FLEET SHOWROOM",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "213.6 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Service Centre", "Spare Parts", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Abu Dhabi"
},
{
  "showroomname": "INFINITI",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "100 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Service Centre", "Spare Parts", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Abu Dhabi"
},
{
  "showroomname": "Ford Showroom",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "213.6 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Service Centre", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Abu Dhabi"
},
{
  "showroomname": "Al Habtoor Motors Royal Car",
  "showroomphone" : "920023345",
  "showroomdistance" : "213.6 m",
  "showroomservices": ["Showroom Sales", "Spare Parts", "Quick Service" ],
  "showroomemail" : "info@hafiz.com",
  "showroomdirection" : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.368971,39.801534",
  "statename" : "Abu Dhabi"
}];


$('#checkbox_div input').on('change', function(){
    var serv_val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  const filteredValues = arr.filter(el => {
   return el.showroomservices.map(elem => elem.toLowerCase()).indexOf(serv_val) !== -1;
  });
  console.log(filteredValues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkbox_div">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="showroom sales">showroom sales</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Service Center">Service Center</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Quick Service">Quick Service</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Spare Parts">Spare Parts</label>
</div>
<ol id="container"></ol>
```

EDIT:

```
$('checkbox_div input').click(function(){
    var serv_val = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON( "petromin.json", function(data) { 

const filteredValues = data.filter(el => {
                return el.showroomservices.map(elem => elem.toLowerCase()).indexOf(serv_val) !== -1;
            });
            console.log(filteredValues);


        filteredValues.forEach(function(obj) { 
            $("ol").append("<li>" + obj.showroomservices.join(', ') + "</li>");
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry mate, I forget to include click event into this snippet. I've updated the answer, enjoy

Comment: hi, good morning dear. can we use it without `const arr = ` <= this

Comment: its not working with ajax 
     `$('#checkbox_div input').on('change', function(){
        var serv_val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $.getJSON('petromin.json', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    const filteredValues = arr.filter(el => {
                    return el.showroomservices.map(elem => elem.toLowerCase()).indexOf(serv_val) !== -1;
                });
                //$('.container').append(filteredValues);
                console.log(filteredValues);        
            });
        });
    });    
`

Comment: its not getting value. could you please review it. i tried a lot to solve it but couldn't.

Comment: Please ensure, that you are getting correct `data` object in response. You can do it using `console.log(data)`

Comment: its sending empty array in console

Comment: and when i checked by `console.log(data)` this it shows all values

Comment: hi, dganenco could you please update here how to get showroomservices(value)  whole object